# How to make classes with objects with defined sizes

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I need to create objects that produce defined squares on a display. I thought if I made a separate class for each object I would be able to make a class instance which would already be of the correct size and use **str** to show what sizes and associated parameter names. I know it doesn't work the way I am doing it as I cannot pass in the parameter args the way I am doing so, I am not even getting a sensible error return but it fails at the line where I have ints passed as args in the method for 'objOne'.

**Code:**

```
class Wide():

    def __init__(self, DW, XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height):
        self.XfromLeftEdge = XfromLeftEdge
        self.YfromTopEdge = YfromTopEdge
        self.Width = Width
        self.Height = Height

    def objOne(self, DW, 141.0, 300.0, 1551.0, 800.0 ): #XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height
        return DW.SetRoi(141.0,300.0,1551.0,800.0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(
            self.XfromLeftEdge = XfromLeftEdge,
            self.YfromTopEdge = YfromTopEdge,
            self.Width = Width,
            self.Height = Height)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'instance object of box, XfromLeftEdge:{},YfromTopEdge: {}, Width:{}, Height:{}'.format(
            self.XfromLeftEdge = XfromLeftEdge,
            self.YfromTopEdge = YfromTopEdge,
            self.Width = Width,
            self.Height = Height)


class Narrow():

    def __init__(self, DW, XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height):
        self.XfromLeftEdge = XfromLeftEdge
        self.YfromTopEdge = YfromTopEdge
        self.Width = Width
        self.Height = Height


    def objOne(self, DW, 141.0, 300.0, 141.0, 800.0 ): #XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height
        return DW.SetRoi(141.0,300.0,141.0,800.0)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(
            self.XfromLeftEdge = XfromLeftEdge,
            self.YfromTopEdge = YfromTopEdge,
            self.Width = Width,
            self.Height = Height)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'instance object of box, XfromLeftEdge:{},YfromTopEdge: {}, Width:{}, Height:{}'.format(
            self.XfromLeftEdge = XfromLeftEdge,
            self.YfromTopEdge = YfromTopEdge,
            self.Width = Width,
            self.Height = Height)


a = Wide()
print(a)
```

**Ouptput**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(base) user % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/.../Desktop/.../play_a.py"
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/.../play_a.py", line 9
    def objOne(self, DropWatch, 141, 300, 1551, 800 ): #XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height
                                ^
```

**Desired Output**
I would like to be able to make a class for Wide, another for narrow, and when I instantiate either I can get predefined size objects and when I print them I can see the parameter names.

Comment: You cannot use numbers as names for function parameters.

Comment: I know, I say that in the question.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding. You keep stating "I cannot pass in the parameter args the way I am doing so". You aren't passing anything. You are defining a method signature. Parameter passing occurs *at the call site*, i.e. when a function is *called* not *defined*

Comment: Hi juanpa, I know I have a fundamental misunderstanding, maybe I just have to pass the args in the script each time I want to make an object of a certain size, what I wanted to know is if there was a way of making the objects of predefined sizes and invoking the size I want in a script without having to pass the args each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a Python function its parameters need to be written as variables, not values. If you want to have predefined values you must do the following:

```
class Wide():
    def __init__(self, XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height):
        # Your code

    def objOne(self, DropWatch, x = 141.0, y = 300.0, w = 1551.0, h = 800.0 ): #XfromLeftEdge, YfromTopEdge, Width, Height
        return DropWatch.SetRoi(x,y,w,h)
```